# Postgres: generate IDs automatically

Tags: sql, postgresql

Objective: Have postgres generate ids automatically

```
CREATE TABLE user_privilege (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    version integer
);
CREATE TABLE

INSERT INTO user_privilege (name, version) values ('XYZ', 1);

ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

ALTER TABLE user_privilege ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('user_privilege_id_seq'::regclass);

ERROR:  relation "user_privilege_id_seq" does not exist
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

I want to keep my id as bigint as all other tables have id as bigint.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the sequence at first:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_privilege_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

and after you can use it:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY user_privilege ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('user_privilege_id_seq'::regclass);
```

Here is the create sequence [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createsequence.html)

Comment: SERIAL and BIGSERIAL data types automatically create a sequence. You don't have to create one manually.

Comment: Yes i know! but it seems that he want learn how to add sequence to a column manually.

Comment: The OP wants to generate ID numbers automatically. In PostgreSQL, the normal way to do that is to use the right data type, not to generate the sequence manually.

Comment: Yes, he wants to generate IDs automatically, and this can be acheved by using a sequence, and sequences can just be added explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: actually Houari's answer works best for me. I have about 70 tables in my database and none of those tables have id as bigserial. All the tables have id as bigint, so I want to keep my id as bigint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate it!

Comment: @riship89 You might also want to associate the sequence with the column: `alter sequence user_privilege_id_seq owned by user_privilege.id`. Then if the table or column is dropped the sequence is also automatically dropped and a  `truncate .. restart identity` will reset the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [use either SERIAL or BIGSERIAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html), not BIGINT.

```
CREATE TABLE user_privilege (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
```

It's not clear whether your table has a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint. But it should.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate it!